# executing unix command with meteor

Tags: linux, meteor, command, execute

I'm new to meteor .
 would anybody  help me ? how could I run a Linux command using meteor ? I'v seen in another post and I recommended to use :

```
sys = __meteor_bootstrap__.require('sys');
```

but I got error and seems meteor bootstrap dose not require function .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically speaking, you cannot simply `require` a node module from a Meteor application. The simplest way to workaround this is to use `meteor:npm` smart package:

```
 meteor add meteorhacks:npm
```

Please read the documentation [here](https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm). Also, you probably don't need `sys` module. Try working with `child_process`:

https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

which is a node standard for running external commands.